# Elastic Beanstalk Docker thin pool full and container became read-only

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My container become read-only in 3 days~, always. I checked docker log and i got "Thin pool has 0 free data blocks which is less than minimum required 2425 free data blocks"..when i deploy again, the containers come back to rw.

I checked docker info too..

[image: docker info]

Someone can help me increase this disks? I searched and saw that the default is 12GB, i tried create two files in .ebextensions/

```
option_settings:
  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    BlockDeviceMappings: /dev/xvdcz=:110:true:gp2
```

and

```
option_settings:
  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    BlockDeviceMappings: /dev/xvdcz=:105::io1:500
```

But didnt work

[image: lsblk]

Comment: cleanup unnecessary images and try to minimize the number of layers in the image

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround is to run `docker save` and write the active image to a tar file, delete the active image (which deleted all the child images), then run `docker load -i` from the tar file and create a single new image. No more errors related to Thin Pool space

Comment: Ty for your response, but, this will not work because the next deploy in Elasticbeanstalk the config would be overwrited. I need increase the default 12GB size >: